# Purpose of KIND= when declaring variables

Tags: fortran

After spending some time trying to understand how `KIND` works in Fortran I'm still in doubt. I would like to know if, e.g., `INTEGER(KIND = c_intptr_t)` is equivalent to`INTEGER(c_intptr_t)`?

If yes, which way is the preferred way?

Comment: For more on kinds, see my post [Doctor Fortran in “It Takes All KINDs”](https://stevelionel.com/drfortran/2017/03/27/doctor-fortran-in-it-takes-all-kinds/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a type declaration the two forms (for kind parameter `k`) `integer (kind = k)` and `integer (k)` are indeed equivalent.

This is true in type declaration statements

```
integer (kind=k) x
integer (k) y       ! x and y are integers with kind parameter k
```

and in other places

```
x = [integer(kind=k) :: 1, 2, 3]
y = [integer(k) :: 1, 2, 3]
```

The same holds for the intrinsic types `real(kind=k)`, `complex(kind=k)` and `logical(kind=k)`.  One has to be careful with `character`:

```
character(kind = k) c  ! Length 1, kind k
character(k) d         ! Length k, default kind
character(l, k) e      ! Length l, kind k
```

Preferred form is subjective and you should follow your style guide consistently.

---

For derived types this is not necessarily the case:

```
type t(k)
  integer, kind :: k=58
end type t

type(t(kind=12)) :: x  ! Not valid: kind parameter is not "kind"
type(t(k=12)) :: y
type(t(12)) :: z

end
```